# Asynchronously extend Nuxt routeRules (static route definition)

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I'm working on my Nuxt 3 [`routeRules`](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config#routerules-1) setup.

Let's say I have two dynamic routes: `/swr/[slug]` and `/prerendered-content/[slug]`.

I want to prerender all of my prerendered-content pages based on a list of slugs that I retrieve from my API during build. This is easy like suggested on [GitHub](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/issues/13949#issuecomment-1397322945). Example:

```js
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    ⋮
    hooks: {
        async 'nitro:config' (nitroConfig) {
            if (nitroConfig.dev) { return; }
            if (!nitroConfig?.prerender?.routes) {
                throw new Error(
                    'nitroConfig.prerender.routes is not defined'
                );
            }
            // Prerender dynamic routes
            const dynamicRoutes = await someApiCallRetunringAnArrayOfUrls();
            nitroConfig.prerender.routes.push(...dynamicRoutes);
        }
    }
});
```

The struggle starts when I try to asynchronously define my swr pages. Those pages are prone to change over time independently from the Nuxt build and therefore should only be cached for a certain TTL and should be revalidated over time.

I tried to do this in the same nitro hook by simply assigning the config to `nitroConfig.routeRules` but that does not work. Non-working example:

```js
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    ⋮
    hooks: {
        async 'nitro:config' (nitroConfig) {
            ⋮
            // Add route rules
            const customRouteRules = await someApiCallRetunringMyRouteRules();
            Object.assign(nitroConfig.routeRules, customRouteRules);
        }
    }
});
```

I know that `routeRules` could be included directly in the nuxt config but I'm unable to define them asynchronously in there.